# How to get XML and HTML report for all browsers in protractor?

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

I need to generate both Jnuit style XML and HTML report but for only 1 browser. How to get it for all browsers.
Using XML creating HTML with help of protractor-html-reporter-2.

```
 
 jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
   new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
     consolidateAll: true,
     savePath: './report/',
   })
 );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Jasmine reporter to create XML report and then user HTML reporter to convert those XML to HTML. However HTML doesn't show results in prettier manner.

Suggestion: You can use Jasmine reporter to create JUnit style XML report and for HTML you may use Protractor beautiful reporter.

In OnPrepare() method in Protractor config:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
browser.get(browserConfig.url);
// Getting browserName from config for File name
browser.getProcessedConfig().then(browser => {
  const browserName = browser.capabilities.browserName;
  const junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    savePath: 'testresults',
    filePrefix: `${browserName}.xmloutput`
  });
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
});

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new htmlReporter(reporter).getJasmine2Reporter());
```

and for reporter

```
const reporter = new htmlReporter({
  baseDirectory: 'Execution_HTMLReports',
  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  pathBuilder: function pathBuilder(spec, descriptions, results, capabilities) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:one-variable-per-declaration
    const currentDate = new Date(),
      day = currentDate.getDate(),
      month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1,
      year = currentDate.getFullYear();

    const validDescriptions = descriptions.map(description => {
      return description.replace('/', '@');
    });

    return path.join(day + '-' + month + '-' + year, capabilities.get('browserName'), validDescriptions.join('-'));
  },
  docName: _env + '_test-report.html',
  screenshotsSubfolder: 'screenshotsOnFailure',
  takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
  excludeSkippedSpecs: true,
  preserveDirectory: false,
  gatherBrowserLogs: true,
  jsonsSubfolder: 'jsonsmetadata',
  clientDefaults: {
    showTotalDurationIn: 'header',
    totalDurationFormat: 'h:m:s',
    columnSettings: {
      displaySessionId: false,
      inlineScreenshots: false
    }
  }
});
```